# How to reset a (redux) reducer state value under any action?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation, redux-persist

I would like to reset my error message that I store on my user reducer in any action, that is, dispatched from any module, but basically navigation.

I looked for getting the action types from `react-navigation` so I could hear them in my user reducer but I couldn't find a way, and writing them explicitly would lead to bad quality code.

I made it work as I show next (notice the **default case**).

But there is a problem: `redux-persist` stop rehydrating my user reducer.

```
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action
  switch (type) {
    case LOGIN_PENDING: {
      return _.merge(state, { loading: true })
    }
    case LOGIN_FULFILLED: {
      return _.merge(state, { ...payload, loading: false })
    }
    case LOGIN_REJECTED: {
      return _.merge(state, { ...initialState, error: payload.message })
    }
    case SIGNUP_PENDING: {
      return _.merge(state, { loading: true })
    }
    case SIGNUP_FULFILLED: {
      return _.merge(state, { ...payload, loading: false })
    }
    case SIGNUP_REJECTED: {
      return _.merge(state, { ...initialState, error: payload.message })
    }
    default: {
      return { ...state, error: '' }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try something like

```
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist/lib/constants'

// in your reducer
case REHYDRATE: {
      return state
    }
default: {
      return _.merge(state, { error: '' })
    }
```